# PHP / MySQL - syntax to sort array results?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Using a custom template (Journal 2) for a PHP-based E-commerce system.
In the control panel, there's a section that loads custom modules.
Problem is, the modules are presented in the order of creation, which makes it hard to find the right module.
I would like to sort them **alphabetically**.

**How & where can I add a sort-by-name feature to this function?**

```
public function all() {
    if (isset($this->get_data['module_type'])) {
        $module_type = $this->db->escape('journal2_' . $this->get_data['module_type']);
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'journal2_modules WHERE module_type = "' . $module_type . '"');
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'journal2_modules');
    }

    foreach ($query->rows as &$row) {
        $row['module_data'] = json_decode($row['module_data'], true);
        if (is_array($row['module_data'])) {
            foreach($row['module_data'] as $key => &$value) {
                if (!in_array($key, array('module_name', 'module_type'))) {
                    unset($row['module_data'][$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $query->rows;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your queries insert an [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) condition like `ORDER BY columnName` to sort by that column.

```
public function all() {
    if (isset($this->get_data['module_type'])) {
        $module_type = $this->db->escape('journal2_' . $this->get_data['module_type']);
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'journal2_modules WHERE module_type = "' . $module_type . '"' . ' ORDER BY ' . $this->get_data['module_order_by']);
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'journal2_modules ORDER BY ' . $this->get_data['module_order_by']);
    }

    foreach ($query->rows as &$row) {
        $row['module_data'] = json_decode($row['module_data'], true);
        if (is_array($row['module_data'])) {
            foreach($row['module_data'] as $key => &$value) {
                if (!in_array($key, array('module_name', 'module_type'))) {
                    unset($row['module_data'][$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $query->rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your query:

```
if (isset($this->get_data['module_type'])) {
    $module_type = $this->db->escape('journal2_' . $this->get_data['module_type']);
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'journal2_modules WHERE module_type = "' . $module_type . '" ORDER BY module_data ASC');
} else {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'journal2_modules ORDER BY module_data ASC');
}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: You're splitting hairs. I don't think using generally accepted English like "Try this..." in any way diminishes a good answer if the code provided actually works for the OP. The quality, for future visitors, can be determined by relevant upvotes or the OP accepting the answer.

Comment: I may be splitting hairs, but you still did not explain to the OP (or future visitors) what changes you made, why you made them and why they should work. I have no problem with "Try this..." answers where an explanation follows. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I didn't need to point out the changes I made because the OP should recognise his own code that I altered, and what the difference are. Plus, the differences were "ORDER BY..." so it's kinda obvious.

Comment: No worries. Just trying to help you improve your answer in such a way as to make it valuable for all levels of developers.

Comment: Well, I've tried both solutions, and they both produce a blank screen. (Well, the menus and sidebars are there, but the area where the list of modules/blocks is supposed to appear, just shows a "Loading O" flicker for a second, and then blanks out.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this?

Comment: If it helps, the DB table "oc_journal2_modules" contains only the following fields: module_id, module_type, module_data. There's no "module_name" unfortunately... but each module does have a name, it's just embedded in "module_data" field:

[module_data]

{"module_name":"Category Short Description - Blue Widgets","module_title":{"value":{"1":""}},"items_per_row":

Soo... can I sort by "the actual string value contained inside 'module_data'" ...?

Comment: SOLVED!

Changed the solution to ORDER BY module_data ASC');

I'd like to mark answers as solved, if you could edit them to reflect the "ORDER BY module_data ASC" change. Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff, glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need  an  specific order, in sql you can use the order  by clause. In your  case could be useful  order by module_name

```
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 
             'journal2_modules WHERE module_type = "' . 
                    $module_type . '"  order by module_name ');
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard   thanks  .. answer  updated  with explanation --